# Best MongoDB schema format for relational data

Tags: mongodb

The premise of the MongoDB instance is that it will hold the user's scores from game sessions, e.g.:

```
SessionId:
GameTitle:
Users:
    User1:
        Score: 109
        Positions: 1st
    User2:
        Score: 100
        Position: 3rd
    User3:
        Score: 105
        Position: 2nd
```

I want to be able to call upon the unique session and be able to get the users, score, and positions from that session but I also want to be able to get all of User1's scores/positions overall, or for a specific GameTitle.

What's the best format the schema to allow this to be possible?

Comment: Three options for you. Make your database relational, then wonder why you didn't use MySQL. OR build your schema to satisfy the most common use case and use aggregation for the other. OR, duplicate your data such that both use cases are satisfied by different collections.

Comment: Seems that you'll need a User model and a Game model at least